Excel edit using Typescript
I am making a website in NextJs, the software is to generate an Excel with information about an invoice.
I have an Excel (Template) with the structure and styles of the Excel that I need to update with the invoice data.
In the public folder I have the template and I access it from a function where I use the XSLX library to update the Excel with the invoice data.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx
https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs
I update the Excel data with the invoice data so I can later download the Excel.
The result should be the Excel with the template styles and the new information.
But when the Excel is downloaded, it has all the data fine, but the Excel style is not there, it returns cells without styles from the template.

const generateExcel = async (data: DocumentField[][], name: string) => {
        // Load the Excel template
        const templatePath = '/templates/PEDIMENTO.xlsx';
        const response = await fetch(templatePath);
        const templateArrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
        const templateWorkbook = XLSX.read(templateArrayBuffer, { type: 'buffer', cellStyles: true });

        // Get the first sheet from the template
        const templateSheet = templateWorkbook.Sheets[templateWorkbook.SheetNames[0]];

        // Clone the template sheet to a new sheet
        const s = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(templateSheet, { header: 1 }) as any[]
        const newSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(s);

        
        XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(templateSheet, [["DATA"]], { origin: 'B3' });


        // Modify the new sheet with your data
        XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(newSheet, data, { skipHeader: true, origin: -1 });

        // Create a new workbook and add the modified sheet
        const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, newSheet, 'Sheet1');

        // Create a blob from the workbook
        const blob = XLSX.writeFile(templateWorkbook, `${name.replace(/\.pdf$/, "")}.xlsx`)

        // Download the Excel file
        const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadLink.download = 'output.xlsx';
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    };

How can I get the Excel with the template styles? Or is there a better library than XSLX where I can achieve that?
Thanks
